# How to find the limit of a function of two variables

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, vector-calculus

I was wondering if there is a method to find the limit of a function of two variables at a point. I tried the following:

```
Limit[(x^4 + y^2)/(x^2 + y^2), (x, y) -> (0, 0)]

Limit[(x^4 + y^2)/(x^2 + y^2), x -> 0, y -> 0]
```

but neither of them worked,

Comment: Along what direction? (I think it matters in this case.) Anyway, maybe something like `Limit[(x^4 + y^2)/(x^2 + y^2) /. y -> m x, x -> 0]`. This allows you to take the limit as `x` and `y` go to zero along the line `y == m*x`.

Comment: The path matters in general. Consider a parametrized curve passing through the origin, substitute the components into your multivariate function, and evaluate the now one-dimensional limit. If your function is sufficiently weird, different paths can give different results.

Comment: Try `WolframAlpha["Limit[(x^4+y^2)/(x^2+y^2),(x,y)\[Rule](0,0)]"]` and then try with `y^2` in numertor changed to `y^4`.

Answer (score 8):

As already mentioned in a comment this limit does not exist without saying more about the way you'd like to approach the point {0,0}.

First of all, I shall take the y^2 in the numerator seriously and not as mistyped y^4.

The 3D plot already shows the problem: in the vicinity of {0,0} the function is not continuous

```
Plot3D[f, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

In the comment it was suggested to walk on the line y = mx but there are many other possibilities some of which will be shown here.

1) In polar coordinates (which is just another formulation of y = m*x) we have

```
fp = (x^4 + y^2)/(x^2 + y^2) /. {x -> r Cos[\[Phi]], y -> r Sin[\[Phi]]} // 
  Simplify

(* Out[129]= r^2 Cos[\[Phi]]^4 + Sin[\[Phi]]^2 *)
```

And the limit r->0 gives

```
Limit[fp, r -> 0]

(* Out[130]= Sin[\[Phi]]^2 *)
```

Which is any real number between 0 and 1, depending on [Phi].

2) Now taking a logarithmic spiral

```
fs = fp /. \[Phi] -> -Log[r]

(* Out[186]= r^2 Cos[Log[r]]^4 + Sin[Log[r]]^2 *)

Limit[%, r -> 0]

(* Out[187]= Interval[{0, 1}] *)
```

and we get any number between 0 and 1.

You can also plot fs. Notice that the picture is more or less scale invariant wth respect to the choice of the upper limit of the plotting interval

```
Plot[fs, {r, 0, 1/100}] (* not shown here *)
```

3) We can also take a discrete sequence

Let the path be given by the points {xn,yn} where

```
xn = 1/FindSequenceFunction[{1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 8, 8, 16, 16}, n]

(*
Out[256]= -(2^(2 - n/2)/(-2 - 2 (-1)^n - Sqrt[2] + (-1)^n Sqrt[2]))
*) 

yn = 1/FindSequenceFunction[{1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 8, 8, 16, 16}, n]

(*
Out[257]= -(2^(2 - n/2)/(-1 + (-1)^(1 + n) - Sqrt[2] + (-1)^n Sqrt[2]))
*)
```

The beginning of the sequence is then

```
s = Table[{xn, yn}, {n, 1, 10}]

(*
Out[258]= {{1, 1}, {1/2, 1}, {1/2, 1/2}, {1/4, 1/2}, {1/4, 1/4}, {1/8, 1/4}, {1/8, 1/8}, {1/16, 1/8}, {1/16, 1/16}, {1/32, 1/16}}
*)
```

Here is the beginning of the path

```
Show[Graphics[{{Blue, Line[{{0, 0}, {1.1, 0}, {1.1, 1.1}, {0, 1.1}, {0, 0}}]},
    Line@s}]]
```

[image]

Our function becomes

fs = f /. {x -> xn, y -> yn};

The plot is

ListPlot[Table[fs, {n, 1, 20}], PlotRange -> {0, 1.1}]

[image]

Closer inspection of fs starts with

```
FullSimplify[fs, {n > 0, n \[Element] Integers}] // Expand

(*
Out[300]= 5/(7 + 3 (-1)^n) + (3 (-1)^n)/(7 + 3 (-1)^n) + (3 2^-n)/(
 7 + 3 (-1)^n) + ((-1)^(1 + n) 2^-n)/(7 + 3 (-1)^n)
*)
```

For large n, only the first two summands remain and we get the asymptotic expression

```
fsa = (5 + 3 (-1)^n)/(7 + 3 (-1)^n);
```

To see the limiting values we splitting fsa into terms with even and odd n

```
fse = Simplify[fsa /. n -> 2 k, k \[Element] Integers]

(* Out[304]= 4/5 *)

fso = Simplify[fsa /. n -> 2 k + 1, k \[Element] Integers]

(* Out[305]= 1/2 *)
```

And we find thet there are two limiting values, 4/5 and 1/2, for k->[Infinity] so that, strictly speaking, a limit does not exist.

*Observations*

a) If we would take y^4 instead of y^2 in the numerator of f the function is continuous (have a look at a 3D plot) and the limit is 0.

b) Interestingly, the formal limit of this type

```
Limit[(3 2^-n)/(7 + 3 (-1)^n), n -> \[Infinity]]

(*
Out[306]= Limit[(3 2^-n)/(7 + 3 (-1)^n), n -> \[Infinity]]
*)
```

is returned unevaluated. Although, as expected

```
Limit[Abs[(3 2^-n)/(7 + 3 (-1)^n)], n -> \[Infinity]]

(* Out[307]= 0 *)
```

Answer (score 3):

In the case you have specified above, there does not exist a unique limit for all sequences $(x_n, y_n) \rightarrow (0,0) \; (n \rightarrow \infty)$. Take for example the following two sequences:

1) $(x_n, 0) \rightarrow (0,0) \; (n \rightarrow \infty)$ with $x_n > 0 \; \forall n$. So we have $(x_n^4 + y_n^2)/(x_n^2 + y_n^2) = x_n^2 \rightarrow 0 \; (n \rightarrow \infty)$.

2) $(0, y_n) \rightarrow (0,0) \; (n \rightarrow \infty)$ with $y_n > 0 \; \forall n$. So we have $(x_n^4 + y_n^2)/(x_n^2 + y_n^2) = 1 \rightarrow 1 \; (n \rightarrow \infty)$.

Obviously the two limits are different, so `Limit` cannot give you a unique result without specifying further restrictions to the sequence.